# Google apps script (GAS) - cross domain reques

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, cross-domain, jsonp

Is there a way to send a cross domain request using GAS, but from the client side script (after script is produced and sanitized by google servers) using something like JSONP ?

Any help or example will be very appreciated.

Momico.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried doing a cross-domain request in Caja, but you may be better off doing a `google.script.run` request to the server side and doing a `UrlFetchApp` request there for the domain you want to access.